# Generate UUID version 4 using given string in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, uuid

I would like to generate UUID version 4 by providing string(e.g androidId in this case). I tried the following approach but it returns UUID version 3, So is there any way to return UUID version 4 by providing a string.

```
val androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(context.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)

val id = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(androidId.toByteArray()) // This returns UUID version 3
```

Comment: You can't. Version 4 UUIDs are [random by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)).

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas for the quick reply, Even I was also under the same impression, But In iOS, they have one API(identifierForVendor) which returns the same UUID version 4  all the time.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor

Comment: "The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them." This suggests that it's just randomly generated and then stored on the device.

Comment: And anyway, why would a v3 UUID not suit your purpose? It's not like v4 is "better"; it's just a different algorithm.

Comment: Yes, you are right identifierForVendor changes when the user uninstalls all the apps from that vendor. The main basic idea behind using UUIDv4 is to avoid collision. We have one strong use case where we need to identify the user's device and block it if we see any fraudulent activity from that device.

For UUIDv4 probability to find a duplicate within 103 trillion is one in a billion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions